# Why do I get an error of trying to convert a string to an nvarchar when there's not string to be converted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data from my on-premise database to my staging database in Azure, but I'm getting an error that says I can't convert a string value to a nvarchar value, which I understand.

But I can't seem to find the column the error is aimed at, since there's only nvarchar.

The error I'm getting is the following:

[image: Error image]

I'll also add images of the datasets I'm using for the databases:

- [The on-premise table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OszYk.png)
- [The table that has to be a copy of the on-premise table (BC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gogiE.png)

Comment: Read further into the error message "String or binary data would be truncated". It's not a *type* issue, it's a *length* issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you, that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) posting your reference as answer to this question to help other community members. Thank you [Youritj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14240017/youritj) for confirming the same.

The error message seems not to be an `Data Type` issue. Its more of an data truncated issue. Fixing the data length should fix the issue